# How to understand and analyse RNA-seq data (for a beginner)?

Tags: rna-seq, rna, transcriptome, gene-expression

I am trying to understand expression of a certain protein across Pseudomonas species. I downloaded an SRA file from NCBI and converted it to a fastaq file. I am not able to understand how to interpret and analyse this file. I want to get the mRNA sequence and see which genes are being expressed and find the mRNA of interest.

How do I proceed with getting the mRNA sequences and then for mapping them to genome?

Comment: For some studies, in GEO they also include the processed counts. You can also see whether it's the case for your study

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRA files are raw sequencing data that have been converted to the NCBI storage format. These can be converted to fastq files, e.g. with fastq-dump from the SRAtoolkit.

Beyond that I suggest you start with the [Hitchhiker's GUide to RNA-seq](https://peerj.com/preprints/27283/) and the [DESeq2 workflow](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html) to get a background. Be sure to extensively browse the web for vignettes, guides and tutorials. YOu will find helpful resources to get started.